# SwiftUI returning a value in nested functions

Tags: swift

I have this swift code:

```
private func checkPhoneNumber(number: String) -> Bool {
       var ret = true
       self.db.collection("customers").whereField("telephone", isEqualTo: number).getDocuments(){ (querysnapshot,err) in
               if querysnapshot!.documents.count>0{
                   self.err="This Phone number is already in use"
                   ret=false
               }
       }
       return ret
   }
```

It sends a request to firebase to check if the phone number is in use. The return value is based on the `getDocuments()` function. However, `getDocuments()` takes 1-2 seconds to complete, heence `checkPhoneNumber` always returns true, before the nested function has time to change the `ret` value. I can't do the `return ret` inside of `getDocuments()`, because it's a different void function. How can I make `checkPhoneNumber` wait till the function inside is completed and then return a value?

Comment: The problem is that `getDocuments()` is an asynchronous function, not simply a nested function call, so you cannot just use the synchronous `return` keyword.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i put the reqeust in  ```DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async```, but nothing changed

Comment: As explained in the linked duplicate target, you need to use a completion handler. `DispatchQueue.async` has nothing to do with your problem or the solution for it.